# udev rule not executed?

Tags: usb

I would like to try this custom firmware for a USB oscilloscope:
https://github.com/rpcope1/Hantek6022API

Setup starts with creating a custom `udev` rule (provided by the project):

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04b4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6022",
TAGS+="uaccess", NAME="hantek1"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04b5", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6022", 
TAGS+="uaccess", NAME="hantek2"
```

I added the `NAME=` parameter at the end because I'm not sure what the device name will be - to see if it shows up at all.

`dmesg` says:

```
[92976.260982] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[92976.401434] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=04b4, idProduct=6022
[92976.401441] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
```

But `udev` is not creating the device file "hantek1" or "hantek2".

Permissions for the `udev` rule are as follows:

```
ls -alh /etc/udev/rules.d/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  203 Jan 25 07:02 60-hantek-6022-usb.rules
```

I'm assuming that `udev` will read those rules as new devices are created or do I need to restart `udev`?

Answer (score 0):

You must issue:

```
udevadm control --reload-rules
```

Comment: ran that command as root, reattached the scope...dmesg shows idVendor and idProduct as above but no "/dev/hantek1" or 2 is showing